# Fedora 28/29 docker LAMP

Tags: docker, port, fedora-28

I'm new to docker, can someone help me with docker LAMP and Fedora 28/29. For some unknown reason when I run docker-compose up -d port 80 does not open or MySQL port 3306 but PHPMyAdmin on 0.0.0.0:8080 is accessible.

**Here is docker lamp GitHub page what I'm using:** https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp/tree/7.2.x

**nmap scan**

```
$ nmap -sT 0.0.0.0
Nmap scan report for 0.0.0.0

PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Comment: Can you add docker-compose logs? It's hard to say what's wrong without more data. Also please add your docker-compose file.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur https://pastebin.com/qCQ1sKFr

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your logs apache won't run because it can't access conf file you have mounted:

```
7.1.x-webserver | apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open config directory /etc/apache2/sites-enabled: Permission denied
```

This can be caused by a few reasons. In order to find the root cause I'll need more data.

1. Which user runs docker-compose up command?
2. Owner and group of volumes you're trying to mount (Show output of `ls -la` on each of those volumes).
3. The user which is being used inside a container.

My guess is that files you're mounting dirs of UserA, and you're mounting them from UserB. Most probably files belong to root and you run from your local user `henry@localhost` right? Maby not a secure solution but try to execute docker-compose from root user.

There is also the case where the UID and GID are different on host and container even though permissions are correct. As a result, you will have permission denied error.

Moreover, how do you even start apache? because I don't see it nither in docker-compose nor Dockerfile of that image? (By looking at [example you're using](https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp/tree/7.2.x))

By the way, you have also problem with mysql container but that's another story:

```
5.7-mysql     | chown: cannot read directory '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
```

Comment: Sorry for so late answer. 
1. in Fedora you need use sudo `docker-compose -up -d` unless you added docker to the group, which I have by following this tutorial https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/docker-installation.html 
`[henry@localhost docker-compose-lamp]$ ls -la
drwxrwxr-x. 2 henry henry 4096 Oct 30 23:32 mysql

`(can't post all list char. limit in comment section)
3. I have no idea how to look user inside a container
Apache is in webserver folder https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp/tree/7.2.x/bin/webserver